# Is it possible to send one bit from one computer to another computer through socket?

Tags: networking, packets

I am working on a project in which i have to send data in bits.

Is it possible to send 1 bit from one computer to another through internet.Most of the people
said to me that minimum internet packet size is 64bytes.If i send 1bit from one computer to another then packet bandwidth is 64bytes.

Answer (score 0):

A TCP or UDP packet consists of a header and data. Maybe you could have one bit of data in the data section, but you would need the header as well. Without the header it would be impossible to send the packet. The header contains all the information required for sending the packet where it is supposed to go and making sure it arrives safely.

Answer (score 0):

I will take "internet packet" to mean Ethernet frame based on the value you give.

An Ethernet frame has a minimum total size of 64 bytes including both header and payload, this is to ensure that the time to transmit a single frame is greater than the round trip time between nodes.

This requirement is a feature of any network that uses CSMA/CD (specifically the CD (collision detection) part), it allows a sensing node to detect a collision whilst still transmitting a frame.

Whilst Ethernet can be used to send a frame smaller than 64 bytes "padding" will be added to ensure the frame is at least 64 bytes.